# shortcodes not working in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, genesis

i'm hoping someone can point out whats going wrong with this WordPress theme. I didn't build the theme, though I know its using Genesis.

http://bloomfire.staging.wpengine.com/partners-new

The issue is on the Referral Partners option (if you click on it, it displays a different tab essentially. But if you scroll down you will see that the tab isn't displaying the shortcode, which is just a simple contact form from Gravity Forms.

I have tried adding in the following code to the functions.php file but it has just been ignored all over:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'do_shortcode' );

global $post;
$content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'solution-tab-3', true );
echo do_shortcode( $content );

add_filter( 'get_post_meta', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'get_post_meta', 'do_shortcode');
```

I don't understand how Genesis isn't allowing a shortcode to be used within the system.
Can anyone help?

Comment: This code doesn't add any shortcodes.

Comment: the problem is that the theme is ignoring the shortcodes, the code above was trying to allow the area to use shortcodes. Sorry I didn't explain myself quite as well as I should've.